# AngularJS directive templates ng-repeat funny substitution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm struggling with angularjs directive templates.  The {{variable}} works in a very strange way inside a ng-repeat,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>here i am</h2>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Howdy</button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" itemlist></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <div> 
        Howdy {{item.itemNum}} {{item.name}}
    </div>
</script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;

    $scope.items = [];

    var newItem = {
        itemNum: 0,
        name: "New"
    };

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        newItem.itemNum = $scope.count;
        console.log('adding item ' + newItem.itemNum);
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
        $scope.count += 1;
    };
});

myApp.directive('itemlist', function ($compile) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
    };
});
```

I have created a jsfiddle showing my problem here:  http://jsfiddle.net/dk253/8jm5tjvf/23/.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are updating the property on the [same object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects) (`newItem`) every time. So it updates all other items in the array because they all just point to the same object or in other words they are all same. You could instead get the copy of the object using angular.copy and push that item.

```
    var item = {
        itemNum: 0,
        name: "New"
    };

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var newItem = angular.copy(item); //Get the copy
        newItem.itemNum = $scope.count;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8a5q07r/)**